# Android handling static Database object

Tags: android, sqlite, static-members

I've got custom adapter class, which incapsulates SQLiteDatabase. Adapter manages db connection:

```
 public AutoDBAdapter(final Context context){
    this.context=context;
    checkDatabase();
    try{
       openDB();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

checkDatabase()
```

method checks if DB exists and copies it from assets if necessary.

```
private void openDB() throws SQLException{
    if(db==null) 
        db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFileName, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

I create AutoDBAdapter class inside my Activities. 
I used this approach because I need my DB to be accessible from multiple activities. I know that that's not a good to do it.

My question: when should I close DB connection? 
Any suggestions would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the db isn't used that often you should close it after each operation. If you are going to use it alot and want to keep it open, you should close it in the onPause method of the Activity.